# CSS - Removing border at the intersection of a circle and a rectangle

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the border at the intersection of a rectangle and a circle like this:
[image]

I've tried to use masks but I can't manage to make it to work, maybe I can get some help?

EDIT:
I've managed to do something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YdsD.png), but I can't find a way to remove the border, I've tried with the answer posted by Laaouatni but he used the background of the circle to get rid of the border, the only problem with that is that i need the circle to be transparent.

```css
.circle {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: .4em solid grey;
}
.levels {
  border: .4em solid grey;
  width: 15em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7.5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="levels"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I've found a way to make it using a mask and some little tricks
https://jsfiddle.net/fg18h7yt/ if anyone wants something like this

Comment: I think the best solution is using `border-bottom: none;` in circle, not sure if is work, I will try

Comment: Why not use an SVG shape for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border-bottom: none;`

or `border-bottom: ColorOfBackground` in this case `White` in your CIRCLE

```css
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid white;
```

IN THE RETTANGLE `transform: translateY(-2.1em);` that make the div go up (so intersecting)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container div {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.5em solid black;
}

.container .circle {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .rectangle {
  border: 0.5em solid black;
  height: 2em;
  width: 30em;
  transform: translateY(-2.1em);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to make the circle transparent so i think this method will not help me, look at my edit, maybe you can help me with it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SVG instead of HTML and CSS. There are lots of tools. Also, lots of online websites can help to design your SVG and directly use them in your HTML code.
More information: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Anyway, this is possible with CSS and using `pseudo-elements` and the `overflow` property of CSS.
More information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

For circle `::before` element created in the `span`. Real circle `::before` and span height is limit the height and hide part of the circle with `overflow:hidden`.

For the bottom part, the top border of the span is removed and two lines are created by `::before` and `::after` elements.

---

```css
.circle {
    width: 5.8em;
    height: 5em;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.9em;
}

.circle::before{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .4em solid grey;
    
}

.levels {
    border: .4em solid grey;
    border-top:0;
    width: 15em;
    height: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7.9em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    
}

.levels::before, .levels::after{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    border: 0 solid grey;   
    border-width:0.4em 0 0 0.4em;   
    height:100%;
    width: 5.5em;
    border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
    margin:0 -0.4em 0 -0.4em;
    float:left;
}

.levels::after{
    border-width:0.4em 0.4em 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 0;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="levels"></div>
</div>
```